# calculate the dimensionless value of pressure vs time

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the dimensionless pressure and plot it with dimensionless time from 0 to 1.  using this equation P_dim.append((2*pi*PP['k']*res['h']/(-Q[840]*pvt['muo']*30))*(3000-Pn_imp[840])).  but I'm getting negative values close to -0.9 which is wrong. How can I calculate it ?

```
P = np.zeros((Nx,Ny))
m=len(t)          # time range for pressure calculation 
print(Pint)
print(np.matmul(Act,Pint) )
A_term_imp=Act + T + J    # first term of pressure equation using implicit method
B_term_imp = np.matmul(Act,Pint) + Q  
Pn_imp = np.linalg.solve(A_term_imp, B_term_imp)  
print(np.linalg.solve(A_term_imp, B_term_imp))
p_840=[]
Pwl=[]
time=[]
P_dim=[]
for j in range(1,m+1):
    A_term_imp=Act + T + J    # first term of pressure equation using implicit method
    B_term_imp = np.matmul(Act,Pint) + Q         # second term of pressure equation using implicit method   
    Pn_imp = np.linalg.solve(A_term_imp, B_term_imp)
    # Pwl.append(Pn_imp)
    # time.append(0.01*j)
    if j==1:
        print(Pn_imp)
    # average = Average(Pn_imp)
    # print(average)
    print('Pressure matrix at time step '+str(j*dt)+' days, implicit method is ',Pn_imp, ' psi', '\n')
    Pint = Pn_imp
    p_840.append(Pn_imp[840])
    
    P_dim.append((2*pi*PP['k']*res['h']/(-Q[840]*pvt['muo']*30))*(3000-Pn_imp[840])     #dimenssionless pressure 
 
            
    for j in range(1,m):
        P=Pn_imp
        P = np.reshape(P, (dy.shape[0], dy.shape[0]))
```

Comment: I assume you realize there's nothing we can do without sample data.  What's the purpose of that final loop?  The statements in it do not depend on `j`.

Comment: it's to reshape P the pressure(with dimension) so I can plot it vs time

Comment: Yes, but you're doing in `m` times, and it is the same operation every time.  You could do it without a loop.

Comment: I modified in my code now. But how can I calculate the average pressures vs time

Comment: There's no way we can tell.  Your equation doesn't depend on your loop variable `j`, so you're going to generate the same answer each time.  I suspect your equation is wrong, but we don't know where it came from.